# How can I convert this simple photoshop workflow to PIL

Tags: python, computer-vision, photoshop

There is this simple trick in photoshop where you can convert a color image into a line art.

In photoshop the process goes like this: https://youtu.be/aPn55fF-Ntk?t=110 video might be little NSFW at some parts but I linked to the important time stamp which is SFW.

Summary if you don't want to watch the video:

1) Turn your image to grayscale and make a copy

2) Change the mode of the top copy to Color Dodge

3) Invert the top image

4) Add gaussian blur

5) Merge 2 layers

My code is below and I am stuck on step 4. I am not exactly sure how to recreate that step in PIL because I have no idea what photoshop is doing. I am not exactly sure where the gaussian blur is applied to, E.g. do I need to apply gaussian to both the original and the copy then add them together? I am very confused on that part.

```
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image
from PIL import ImageFilter
import PIL.ImageOps 

def dodge(front,back):
    # The formula comes from http://www.adobe.com/devnet/pdf/pdfs/blend_modes.pdf
    result=back*256.0/(256.0-front) 
    result[result>255]=255
    result[front==255]=255
    return result.astype('uint8')

fname = 'C:/Users/Luke Chen/Desktop/test.JPG'

img = Image.open(fname,'r').convert('L') # turn image to grayscale

arr = np.asarray(img)

img_blur = img.filter(ImageFilter.BLUR) 

blur = np.asarray(img_blur)

result = dodge(front=blur, back=arr) # color doge copy

result = Image.fromarray(result, 'L')

result = PIL.ImageOps.invert(result) # invert the color doge copy

# toDO Do something with gaussian blur?? and merge both images. 

result.show()
```

Comment: You need to apply the gaussian blur to the copy *or* the original, but *not* both

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Updated Answer**

I was busy yesterday, but have some time this morning, so here is a way of doing it with Python and `numpy`. It may be a little clumsy as I am just a beginner with Python but it works and you can see how to do some things and can fiddle with it to make it do what you want.

```
#!/usr/local/bin/python3

import numpy as np
from PIL import Image, ImageFilter

# Load image and convert to Lightness
i0=Image.open('image.png').convert('L')

# Copy original image and Gaussian blur the copy
i1=i0.copy().filter(ImageFilter.GaussianBlur(3))

# Convert both images to numpy arrays to do maths - this part is probably clumsy
i0=np.array(i0,dtype=np.float32) / 255
i1=np.array(i1,dtype=np.float32) / 255
result=i0/i1
result*=255
result=np.clip(result,0,255)
result=result.astype(np.uint8)
result=Image.fromarray(result, 'L')

result.save("result.png")
```

[image]

**Original Answer**

It's a bit late here to do too much Python and numpy, but I can show you how to get the effect and tell you the steps using **ImageMagick** and may do the `numpy` thing tomorrow.

So, start with this:

[image]

And then, using **ImageMagick** in Terminal, run this:

```
convert image.png -colorspace gray \( +clone -blur 0x3 \) -compose dividesrc -composite  result.png
```

[image]

So, if I explain that command, you can do the `numpy` stuff, or I'll do it tomorrow. It says... *"Load the input image and convert it to greyscale. Make a copy of the greyscale image and blur just the copy. Divide the original image by the blurred copy. Save the result."*.

Comment: You might consider using Python Wand, which is based upon Imagemagick. It should have blur and composite color_dodge and negate (for the invert), since those functions are available in Imagemagick.